# Error Making Linphone SDK For iPhone iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, makefile, sip, linphone

I'm trying to build linphone SDK for iPhone, and I've installed all the perquisites and dependencies. When I try to make the SDK ( Using `make all` command ) I get the following error :

```
make -f  builder-iphone-simulator.mk enable_gpl_third_parties=yes enable_zrtp=no   enable_opus=yes enable_debug=no enable_ffmpeg=yes all  \
&& make -f  builder-iphone-os.mk  enable_gpl_third_parties=yes enable_zrtp=no   enable_opus=yes enable_debug=no enable_ffmpeg=yes all  \
&& make -f  builder-iphone-os.mk  host=armv7s-apple-darwin enable_gpl_third_parties=yes enable_zrtp=no   enable_opus=yes enable_debug=no enable_ffmpeg=yes all  \
&& make -f builder-iphone-os.mk delivery-sdk 
mkdir -p /Users/Unkn0wn/Developer/GIT/linphone-iphone/submodules/build/..//../liblinphone-sdk/i386-apple-darwin/include
mkdir -p /Users/Unkn0wn/Developer/GIT/linphone-iphone/submodules/build/..//../liblinphone-sdk/i386-apple-darwin/lib/pkgconfig
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/Users/Unkn0wn/Developer/GIT/linphone-iphone/submodules/build/..//externals/polarssl/Makefile', needed by `update-tree'.  Stop.
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

Anybody knows what the problem is and what should I do ?

Comment: At a wild guess, you never passed the `--recursive` into the git clone command.

Comment: I have passed it, but I doubt if it has worked properly, because I had a very unstable connection ! I'm trying to redownload the linphone SDK for iPhone ! and will post updates if it was the reason or not !

Comment: Yeah, re-cloning solved the problem ;)
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yes, I mentioned solution in the above